# Zend FlashMessenger cant find Plugin

Tags: zend-framework

Hello guys I am using PHP 5.2.6-1 and Zend 1.9, I am trying to use the FlashMessenger plugin like this:

```
$flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
$flashMessenger->addMessage('We did something in the last request');
```

but I get a weird error message:

Message: Plugin by name 'FlashMessenger' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/var/www/webtest.com/mycaseapp/views/helpers/

Comment: Are you accessing this from a view or a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action controller you should have

```
$flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
$flashMessenger->addMessage('We did something in the last request');
$this->view->messages = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
```

Then in your view script you would have something like

```
<?php
foreach($this->messages()as $message){
    echo $message . "<br/>";
}
```

[See the manual page here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger)

Comment: yep. Thanks for pointing that out. Very stupid mistake :P I tohoug I will read from the message in the view but I need of course to get its data while still in the controller! Greate.